# Побитовые операции и сдвиги (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c

Имеется следующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
   int UnitStateWord;
   unsigned char c,f;
   printf("Insert state code (0 - 31) >");
   scanf("%d",&c);
   UnitStateWord = (c & 0x1F) << 11;
   printf("\n? The result = %04x\n", UnitStateWord);
   printf("Insert if error exists (0/1) >");
   scanf("%d",&f);
   UnitStateWord |= (f & 1) << 9;
   printf("\n? The result = %04x\n", UnitStateWord);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На вход поступило: 1, затем ещё 1, вывод видно в The result.
Почему после второго ввода и выполнении соответствующей операции

> UnitStateWord |= (c & 1) << 9;

Переменная UnitStateWorld = 200? В моем понимании она должна быть равна A00.

Comment: Сразу бросается в глаза опечатка: вы читаете в переменную `f`, но дальше не используете её. Вряд ли это повлияет на результат, но всё же.

Comment: @Arhad благодарю, исправил данную опечатку, результат получился немного другой, но всё равно не такой, как я предполагал

Comment: Чем компилировали и как? VC++ дает `0a00`

Comment: Да, кстати, поменяйте в scanf'ах `%d` на `%hhd` - все-таки не `int` считываете, мало ли как вы там память запарываете...

Comment: У вас же C++. Замените `scanf()` на `std::cin`, а `printf()` — на `std::cout`.

Comment: @Arhad сейчас попробую, но преподаватель принципиально потребовал использовать scanf, и как я могу с помощью std::cin ввести в char значение integer?

Comment: @Arhad, С++ не запрещает использовать <cstdio> -- <cstdio> такая же библиотека, как и <iostream>. Мало того, <cstdio> гибче, проще, удобнее, а код с ней намного более читабелен, чем с <iostream>.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, затирание соседней памяти из-за неверного спецификатора `%d`.

Замените его на `%hhd` - для `unsigned char`.

Comment: Комплирую GNU GCC Compiler в IDE Code Blocks или с помощью некого MinGW64 в IDE Dev-C.

Comment: Поменял, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: https://ideone.com/JNYXYu - у вас такой результат? нет?

Comment: нет, мой результат на скриншоте, а вот у вас получился верный результат, получается проблема в компиляторе?

Comment: уберите обьявление UnitStateWord  и  инициализируйте сразу:  int  UnitStateWord = ... Может  ваш компилятор не любит лишнего ( хаха ) У меня тоже все правильно работает

Answer (score 0):

У вас четыре ошибки при интерпретации стандартного ввода. Во-первых спецификатор формата для `unsigned char` должен быть `%hhu` (доступен начиная с С++11, до этого заполнить переменные такого типа было нельзя). Во вторых отсутствует проверка значения, возвращаемого `scanf`, поэтому в обе переменные `c` и `f` так и могут остаться неинициализированными.

Comment: Подразумевается, что пользователь введет верные данные в scanf. Исправил, выдает опять тоже самое.

Comment: @АрбузАлександр [Не воспроизводится](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bTomhq83G6u1l4WI)

Answer (score 0):

Мучаясь в течение дня с теми или иными способами, дабы исправить эту проблему, сменил IDE и соответственно компилятор на VC. 
Всё работает без ошибок, в чём проблема - неизвестно.